# Meekro DB query

Tags: meekro

What would be the equivalent query in Meekro DB to this working one I have?:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM data WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)";
```

Not working query:

```
DB::delete('data', "date=%s", '(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK)');
```